# Python 3 script doesnt run properly in Python 3.4 but Python 2 script works

Tags: python, input

I am using Python 3.4 to run this scripts in Windows 8.1.
This is a part of my script which I believe is causing problems:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print("Enter a sentence: ",end="")
    sen = sys.stdin.readline()
    print("\nThe Longest word in the sentence is {}".format(longestWord(sen)))
    sys.stdin.readline()
```

I have used calls to sys.stdin.readline() because input() would give me an EOF error. That solved the EOF error but now I get another error pointing to the end argument in the print saying its an syntax error. This problems only occur when I run it as a top level script but work properly in IDLE. Running this as a top level script gives me a SyntaxError for the at the 'end' argument in the print statment and if I use input() instead of sys.stdin.readline().

I then changed the script to work with 2.x

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sen = raw_input("Enter a sentence: ")
    print "\nThe Longest word in the sentence is {}".format(longestWord(sen))
    raw_input()
```

This script works properly in Python 2.7 but also in 3.4. I was expecting errors for the raw_input function and print statement but I don't get them.
Both scripts however work properly in IDLE 3.4.
Can someone please explain whats happening?

Comment: Where your script fails? It isn't really clear in your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple explanation is that you were confused and the script was originally run with python 2, not 3. That's why the syntax error on `end=` happened.

Python 2:

```
In [1]: print("Enter a sentence: ",end="")
  File "<ipython-input-1-fa5e4168bd19>", line 1
    print("Enter a sentence: ",end="")
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python 3:

```
In [1]: print("Enter a sentence: ",end="")
Enter a sentence:
```

The confusion continues, because the second script cannot work under python 3:

```
In [1]: print "\nThe Longest word in the sentence is {}".format(longestWord(sen))
  File "<ipython-input-1-ae375034dd27>", line 1
    print "\nThe Longest word in the sentence is {}".format(longestWord(sen))
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In python 3 `print` is a function and this line just wouldn't work.

Comment: Actually I am pretty sure both scripts were run with Python 3.4. It is the default on my system and the titlebar of the window shows its as Python34.

Comment: Title bar can say anything really. Try printing out `sys.version` to see it.

Comment: This script **can't** run under Pyhon 3.x.

Comment: Yeah you are right. The script is running under Python 2.7 even though the title bar says it is running under 3.4. Thanks..